# MS Access 2010 Form Box Control Source IIF Statement

Tags: forms, ms-access, expression, ms-access-2010, iif

I am running into the Max Character Issue when trying to put my IIF statement into a box I have created for the calculation of a score on my form. The box code is:

```
=IIf([cbov1]="na" And [cbov2]="na" And [cbov3]="na" And [cbov4]="na" And [cbov5]="na" And [cboV6]="na" And [cboV7]="na" And [cboV8]="na" And [cboV9]="na" And [cboV10]="na" And [cboV11]="na" And [cboV12]="na" And [cboV13]="na" And [cboi1]="na" And [cboi2]="na" And [cboi3]="na" And [cboi4]="na" And [cbop1]="na" And [cbop2]="na" And [cbop3]="na" And [cbop4]="na" And [cbop5]="na" And [cbop6]="na" And [cbop7]="na" And [cbop8]="na" And [cbop9]="na" And [cbop10]="na" And [cbop11]="na" And [cbof1]="na" And [cbof2]="na" And [cbof3]="na" And [cbof4]="na" And [cbof5]="na" And [cbof6]="na" And [cbof7]="na" And [cbof8]="na" And [cbof9]="na" And [cbof10]="na" And [cbom1]="na" And [cbom2]="na" And [cbom3]="na" And [cbom4]="na" And [cbom5]="na" And [cbom7]="na" And [cbom8]="na" And [cbom9]="na" And [cbom10]="na" And [cbom6]="na",0,(IIf([cboV1]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cbov2]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cbov3]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cbov4]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cbov5]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cboV6]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV7]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV8]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV9]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV10]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV11]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV12]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cboV13]="yes",0,0)+IIf([cboi1]="yes",5,0)+IIf([cboi2]="yes",3,0)+IIf([cboi3]="yes",3,0)+ IIf([cboi4]="yes",4,0)+IIf([cbop1]="yes",5,0)+IIf([cbop2]="yes",5,0)+IIf([cbop3]="yes",5,0)+IIf([cbop4]="yes",5,0)+ IIf([cbop5]="yes",5,0)+ IIf([cbop6]="yes",4,0)+ IIf([cbop7]="yes",4,0)+ IIf([cbop8]="yes",4,0)+ IIf([cbop9]="yes",4,0)+ IIf([cbop10]="yes",2,0)+IIf([cbop11]="yes",2,0)+IIf([cbof1]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbof2]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbof3]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbof4]="yes",1,0)+ IIf([cbof5]="yes",1,0)+ IIf([cbof6]="yes",1,0)+ IIf([cbof10]="yes",0,0)+ IIf([cbof7]="yes",3,0)+ IIf([cbof8]="yes",3,0)+ IIf([cbof9]="yes",3,0)+IIf([cbom1]="yes",5,0)+IIf([cbom2]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbom3]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbom4]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbom5]="yes",1,0)+IIf([cbom6]="yes",1,0) +IIf([cbom7]="yes",3,0) +IIf([cbom8]="yes",2,0) +IIf([cbom9]="yes",5,0) +IIf([cbom10]="yes",5,0))/(IIf([cboV1]="na",0,0)+IIf([cbov2]="na",0,0)+IIf([cbov3]="na",0,0)+IIf([cbov4]="na",0,0)+IIf([cbov5]="na",0,0)+IIf([cboV6]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV7]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV8]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV9]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV10]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV11]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV12]="na",0,0)+ IIf([cboV13]="na",0,0)+IIf([cboi1]="na",0,5)+IIf([cboi2]="na",0,3)+IIf([cboi3]="na",0,3)+ IIf([cboi4]="na",0,4)+IIf([cbop1]="na",0,5)+IIf([cbop2]="na",0,5)+IIf([cbop3]="na",0,5)+IIf([cbop4]="na",0,5)+ IIf([cbop5]="na",0,5)+ IIf([cbop6]="na",0,4)+ IIf([cbop7]="na",0,4)+ IIf([cbop8]="na",0,4)+ IIf([cbop9]="na",0,4)+ IIf([cbop10]="na",0,2)+ IIf([cbop11]="na",0,2)+IIf([cbof1]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbof2]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbof3]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbof4]="na",0,1)+ +IIf([cbof5]="na",0,1)+ +IIf([cbof6]="na",0,1)+ +IIf([cbof7]="na",0,3)+ +IIf([cbof8]="na",0,3)+ +IIf([cbof9]="na",0,3)+ +IIf([cbof10]="na",0,0)+IIf([cbom1]="na",0,5)+IIf([cbom2]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbom3]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbom4]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbom5]="na",0,1)+IIf([cbom6]="na",0,1) +IIf([cbom7]="na",0,3) +IIf([cbom8]="na",0,2) +IIf([cbom9]="na",0,5) +IIf([cbom10]="na",0,5)))*(IIf([cbov1]="no" Or [cbov2]="no" Or [cbov3]="no" Or [cbov4]="no" Or [cbov5]="no" Or [cboV6]="no" Or [cboV7]="no" Or [cboV8]="no" Or [cboV9]="no" Or [cboV10]="no" Or [cboV11]="no" Or [cboV12]="no" Or [cboV13]="no",0,1))
```

The purpose of the score is to score "Yes" with points, Score "No" as no points, and then have "NA" remove from the overall score. So if a person has 67 out of 67 points, they get a 100. The maximum points is 100 if all questions are answered "Yes" or "No". I need to have all portions of the calculation because CBOV1-13 have a stipulation of if they are "No" the score is automatically 0%.

I don't know of a work around for the MAX CHARACTER you get within the expression builder on the Control Source box via the properties sheet.

Any help on a work around for this issue or ways to make the code shorten and fit with the same end result would be a huge help.

Comment: Are you sure you have your table design normalized?

Comment: Can you clarify this question?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would be tempted to have my field as a numeric (0,1,2 instead of "na,Yes,No"
Then you could use addition...IIF{cvb01 + Cvb02 +cvb03 = 0, 0 ,...else

Using Strings
I can think of two ways.  One in the formula using concatenation (ugly)
IIF[cvb01] & [cvb02] & [cvb03] = "NANANA", 0 , ...Else)

I would be more tempted to write a function to take care of it.

```
dim NAcount as integer
Dim YesCount as integer
Dim NoCount as integer

dim ctr as integer
dim StrAns as string

for ctr = 1 to 10
 StrAns = Fields ("cvb" & Ctr)

Select case StrAns
   Case "NA"
     NaCount = NACount + 1
     '...add values here

   Case "Yes"
     '...more values go here

   Case "No"
     '... more values
End Select

Next Ctr
...
```

Comment: @Northcat When you say write a function, would I do this in the "View Code" section of Access? I am not fully versed in VBA Code so when you have the "..." is that suppose to be something inserted? Next would be if I do this in the VBA code, can the score show up on the form as a continuing calculation?